# Ambiguity of constructor arguments in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I've got an error saying about type ambiguity:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blankRestoreFromRecycleUiOperation' defined in URL: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
```

Here is my spring xml mapping:

```
<bean id="blankRestoreFromRecycleUiOperation" class="BlankRestoreFromRecycleUiOperation">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="blankTab"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

My java class:

```
public class BlankRestoreFromRecycleUiOperation implements RestoreFromRecycleUiOperationAware {

       private String tab;
       private boolean green;

       public BlankRestoreFromRecycleUiOperation(String tab, boolean green) {
            this.tab = tab;
            this.green = green;
       }
}
```

So, the other similar questions says about proper constructor arguments indexing and naming but here I guess I missed something else. Also before posting I tried adding arguments type like this:

```
<bean id="blankRestoreFromRecycleUiOperation" class="BlankRestoreFromRecycleUiOperation">
    <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String" value="blankTab"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" type="boolean" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Then got the same error.

Could you specify either the correct way to do so or missing parts? Thanks for your answers in advance.

Solved: the problem was related to IDE and gradle versions. There was 2 separated and different versions of Spring caused whole app work wrong. Anyway thanks for your answers.

Comment: Have you added a `name` attribute already?

Comment: Can you please show your project structure?

Comment: Are there other constructors that could confuse Spring ?

Comment: I am not a spring expert, but it says id="blankRestoreFromRecycleUiOperation" there. But your class name starts UpperCase? Could it be that your id should read "Blank..." as well, matching the casing of the java class?

Comment: Please add the fullstracktrace... Also is your `BlankRestoreFromRecycleUiOperation` accidentally annotated with `@Component` or something like that?

Comment: mrkernelpanic - yes, did it, of course;
 M. Deinum - there're no annotations in the class;
GhostCat, MohammadReza Alagheband - tried these ones. Got the same error

Comment: Please show your project structure. It might have got to do something with it. Also, you'd need to specify the `class` with complete namespace with respect to the sourcepath.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<bean id="blankRestoreFromRecycleUiOperation" class="ua.com.profitsoft.bo.report.mtsbu.ui.operation.impl.BlankRestoreFromRecycleUiOperation">

        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String">
            <value>blankTab</value>
        </constructor-arg>

        <constructor-arg type="boolean">
            <value>true</value>
        </constructor-arg>

    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

just try in your XML mapping in class = "com.jwt.spring.BlankRestoreFromRecycleUiOperation">
maybe it helps because this type of error are called injection type ambiguities.
I hope it will help.